# Draw string with alpha animation

Tags: ios, swift, string, cabasicanimation

I am drawing a `string` on a `view` as

```
string.draw(at: point withAttributes: attributes)
```

I want to add some animation effect to the string, basically the alpha value - from 0 to 1 for a duration of 1.0 second. How would I achieve it?

Comment: You should provide a bit more info. You seem to be drawing to a `CGContext`, are you drawing anything else into that context? Do you want to animate only the text fading in? Are you using `UIKit` or `AppKit`?

Comment: Yes. I am drawing only the string to `CGContext`. I am using `UIKit`

Comment: Context are drawn whenever a re-draw is requested. You could use a `DisplayLink` to request a re-draw on your context every frame and update the alpha, but that's overkill for what you need. Easiest way would be to put your text on its own `UILabel` and animate that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate the view `layer` opacity with `CABasicAnimation`, i.e:

```
let view = // view rendering string

let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
animation.fromValue = 0
animation.toValue = 1
animation.duration = 1

// add animation
view.layer.add(animation, key: "opacity")

// commit the final opacity value that will be used after animation completes
view.layer.opacity = 1
```

You may also want to use `CATextLayer` instead of rendering the string in `UIView.draw`. In that case you would animate the `opacity` of the text layer.

```
let view = // view rendering string

let textLayer = CATextLayer()
textLayer.string = "my text"
textLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds

view.layer.addSublayer(textLayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

An other understanding of your request:

***typewriter effect text animation***

one character by one,

- the character shown , alpha 1
- the character to be shown, alpha 0

```
extension UILabel{
    func setTyping(text content: String, duration: TimeInterval = 5.0) {
      text = ""
      let dalay = duration / TimeInterval(content.count)
      let writingTask = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in
        guard let `self` = self else {return}
        content.forEach { char in
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.text?.append(char)
          }
          Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: dalay)
        }
      }
        
      let queue: DispatchQueue = .init(label: "typespeed", qos: .userInteractive)
      queue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05, execute: writingTask)
    }
}
```